# no suitable driver for jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:servicename

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I know, this has already been posted but none of the solutions worked. I am really stuck at this point. I am working on installation of oracle 12c SOA suite. I am installing PIP3.4. However, when I run from command, I get this error:

```
no suitable driver for jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:servicename.
```

I also tried following URL:

```
no suitable driver for jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/servicename
```

ojdbc6 and ojdbc7 are already present there. I am using Oracle SOA 12C and jdk1.8.0_51. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I am able to connect to DB from JDeveloper but its giving error from command line bat file execution.

Comment: ojdbc6/7 are already present where? In your classpath?

Comment: They are present in (adapter home)/lib path.

Comment: The fact it is in some lib folder, doesn't mean it is on the runtime classpath of your application. Check the classpath configuration of your application.

Comment: I am not referring it from java project. I am running command suggested by oracle which internally connects to DB. Below is my failing command: ant -f %AIA_HOME%/Infrastructure/Install/AID/AIAInstallDriver.xml -DDeploymentPlan=%AIA_HOME%/pips/AgileToSAP/DeploymentPlans/AgileToSAPDP.xml -DPropertiesFile=%AIA_INSTANCE%/config/AIAInstallProperties.xml -DDeploymentPolicyFile=%AIA_HOME%/pips/AgileToSAP/DeploymentPlans/AgileToSAPConditionalPolicy.xml -DSupplementaryDeploymentPlan=%AIA_HOME%/pips/AgileToSAP/DeploymentPlans/AgileToSAPSupplementaryDP.xml

Comment: what oracle documentation referred is to put ojdbc in lib and restart weblogic server.

Comment: And what classpath is available to Ant? Does the AIAInstallDriver.xml file set it to something that includes the ojdbc file location?

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting to the database using SQLPLUS and also using fully qualified URL.

sqlplus scott/tiger@"(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=servicename)))"

Fully qualified URL = jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=servicename)))

Comment: It connects from there. Anyways, I am looking into it. If find some solution, I will share here !!